# C++ Static_cast over a pointer to virtual base class

Tags: c++, casting, downcast, virtual-inheritance, static-cast

After about 6 o 7 years programming nearly exclusively on C++, I've discovered that:

```
struct A
{
   virtual ~A() = 0; // Abstract class
};

A::~A() {}

struct B : virtual A
{};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B;
    (void)static_cast<B*>(a);

    return 0;
}
```

throws a compiler error, because the standard doesn't allow to make a static cast from a pointer to a virtual base class. I assume that that's related to the memory layout associated to a virtual base class, but I would like to know the details.

Comment: your code compiles; didn't you mean `struct B : public virtual A`?

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Solved (yes, I meant that)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, the memory image of `virtual A` within `B` and that of `A` might differ. Without allowing it to differ, the well-known 'dared diamond' could not be solved (well, at least not easily, since we cannot request `A` to be aware of this and set up an ABI that's preferable to us). Think of `virtual A` as having a virtual function for each function and member access of `A` in `B`. It's not necessarily implemented like that, but you might model it that way.